# How to defeat Fnarf

Tags: the-bards-tale

It seems to be impossible to defeat **Fnarf**!

I already spent half an hour trying all kinds of combinations and nothing works.

Those three discussions say it's possible but none provide a good strategy:

1. [Steam community](https://steamcommunity.com/app/41900/discussions/0/864959810052321054/)
2. [IGN](http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/general-fnarf-tips-highland-park.70925919/)
3. [idlethumbs](https://www.idlethumbs.net/forums/topic/2973-the-bards-tale-beating-fnarf/)

Is there a strategy like location, weapon and follower that I need to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with my own answer because I finally found a combination that would hurt a tiny bit of Fnarf, so you have to keep doing that a million times until he is dead.

When you enter the area through the ramp, a magic door will close behind you. When you are very near or touching that door, the two Fnarf spawns will "forget" about you and give up chasing you. Sometimes they might stick around and fight, so be prepared with the following steps:

1. Arm yourself with the bow;
2. Summon the Crone for healing;
3. Go as fast as you can to a place where you can see Fnarf and shoot 1 or 2 arrows while he is summoning his spawns.
4. Run away from the spawns to the magic barrier;
5. Arm yourself with the two swords or anything that would defeat the spawns in case they come too close.
6. When they are gone (dead or forgot about you), start all over again from step 1.

That's it... one arrow hit at a time until he is dead.

**NOTE: No other weapon will work because he keeps disappearing if you get too close.**

I would also try the vorpal rat to distract the spawns for an extra shot with the bow, but if they get too close to you and you are holding a bow, there is a good chance you will die.

Answer (score 1):

Use the bodyguard and the crone. equip the box, and ignore the summons from Fnarf. The crone, your dog and the bodyguard all keep em busy while you shoot Fnarf. Just keep an eye on everyones health. I had one summon on me, one on the bodyguard and just shot the hell out of Fnarf.